# What is more required to work with your Big commerce API except cUrl?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Hi i have written this below code to work with bigcommerce API . But it seems it have some server issue . My server is PHP >5.3 & curl enabled but API seems is not returning any response . Can any one help me how to solve that issue ?

Here is my code

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'demo'.':'.'df38dd10e9665a3cfa667817d78ec91ee9384bc3');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);

 echo "<textarea>".$result."</textarea>";

 phpinfo();
```

You can check it into my live server http://fuzonmedia.com/big/server_test.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All requests to the Bigcommerce API need to be encrypted using the SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA cipher. Most initial problems with the API are due to not telling cURL to use the correct cipher when sending a request. As your system is using the [NSS](http://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/mod_nss.git/plain/docs/mod_nss.html) library to handle the encrypting you can tell cURL which cipher to use with the following line of code.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_rc4_128_sha');
```

If this doesn't solve your issue you will need to check to see if cURL is returning any errors. You can do this by modifying your code as follows.

```
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    if ($result === false) {
        echo '<textarea>'.curl_error($ch).'</textarea>'; 
    } else {
        echo "<textarea>".$result."</textarea>";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Outputting the error message may give you more clues as to what is going wrong. You can also obtain more information by switching on the **verbose** option. Note that this information is outputted to ***STDERR*** so you will not see it on your web page unless you redirect ***STDERR*** to ***STDOUT***, i.e. the browser window.

```
    // Switch on verbose information and display it on the web page.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));
```

Hope the above helps.

Kind Regards,
David

Comment: I don't think that the issue is cipher related. I might be wrong though. Looks to me more of a SSL cert problem.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but setting _CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER_ to _false_ should have disable verifying of the SSL certificate. The trouble is without seeing any of the information been returned from cURL the problem could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the previous answer - You can also use the Bigcommerce PHP library (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) which provides an easier way to interact with the APIs using PHP. You can access products like -

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

    foreach($products as $product) {
        echo $product->name;
        echo $product->price;
    }
```

Regards to David's answer about cipher, you need to set it to rsa_rc4_128_sha, similar to following. Hopefully this helps. -

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com',
'username' => 'admin',
'api_key' => 'xxxxxx'
));
Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('rsa_rc4_128_sha')
Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);
```